# Что означает слово Order в значении метода?

Tags: php

Что означает слово `Order` в значении метода и это как то влияет на `$order`?

```
 public static function onOrderSave(Order $order)
 { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Так объявляется тип передаваемого параметра. То есть данная функция примет в `$order` только объект `Order` или наследуемые от него классы.

Цитата из документации:

> Объявления типов позволяют функциям строго задавать тип передаваемых
>   параметров. Передача в функцию значений несоответствующего типа будет
>   приводить к ошибке: в PHP 5 это будет обрабатываемая фатальная ошибка,
>   а в PHP 7 будет выбрасываться исключение TypeError.

Прочитать можете подробней в [официальной документации](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php), раздел `Объявление типов`